# How I get Server Name and Instance Name and use in app.config

Tags: c#, linq

I search few articles but not able to solve my problem, please help me to solve the issue.

In my application I use Linq to Sql and in app.config my connection string is like

```
computername/instancename
```

for computer name I use `(local)` but how I know the client computer have default instance or named instance?

Please help me.

## update

In Sql Server 2008 when I call `select @@SERVICENAME` it returns me instance name like `SQLEXPRESS`

Exactly same I need in app.config file.

I want to save this `@@SERVICENAME` in variable and in Data Source I use this variable like `Data Source = (local)/@@SERVICENAME`

I use Linq to Sql, please guide me how I achieve this goal.

Comment: What about using a simple `.`?

Comment: I try with . (dot) but I receive error related to failure to established connected error 40 and error 2

Comment: Any help please